# Uploading Large CSV File into Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to upload large CSV document into mysql database can anyone help me out, the table consist of 10 fields but i want to upload into only 5 fields of the table without a heading. I want this done with php in the browser

```
$filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
<?php
    if($_FILES["file"]["type"] != "application/vnd.ms-excel"){
       die("This is not a CSV file.");
    }
    elseif(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'])){
     $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = 'root';
     $dbpass = '';
     $dbname = 'cbt_software';
     $link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error        connecting to mysql server');
   mysql_select_db('cbt_software') or die(mysql_error());
   //Process the CSV file
   $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['name'], "r");
   $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";"); 
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
      $att0 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]);
      $att1 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]);
      $att2 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]);
      $att3 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[3]);
      $att4 = mysql_real_escape_string($data[4]);  

      $sql = "INSERT INTO `course_reg` (`coursecode`,`coursename`,`coursedescription`,`coursemaster`,`courselevel`)VALUES     ('$att0','$att1','$att2','$att3','$att4')";
      mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_close($link);
   echo "CSV file successfully imported.";
}
else{
   die("You shouldn't be here");
}
?>
```

At first this imported all the field from the csv into just one field in the database and after i tampered with the code it is not recognicing it a s a CSV file.

Comment: It appears you're testing whether the uploaded file is an Excel spreadsheet, not a CSV file.  Either skip that check, or check the filename ended in ".csv" (of course, that doesn't mean it's really a CSV file).

Comment: Also, you haven't checked that the fopen() call succeeds.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're looking at the wrong filename - $_FILES['file']['name'] is the name supplied by the client, you want $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] for the filename the uploaded temporary file was stored on the server as.  (With the 'file' being changed to the name of the file input box.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have the appropriate permissions, you can do so directly in MySQL with the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/load-data.html or the `mysqlimport` utility, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysqlimport.html

Both methods will allow you to specify which columns the data should go in, for instance:

`LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.txt' INTO TABLE 'mytable' (col1, col2, col3, ...)`

or

`mysqlimport --columns='col1,col2,...' tablename.csv`

If you intend to do it from PHP, you should be able to read each line of the CSV file and execute an appropriate SQL INSERT query naming the appropriate columns (although that will not be as efficient as doing it directly in MySQL).

EDIT: I should add that you haven't mentioned what you've tried so far or what you're finding difficult; if you're stuck on something in particular, rather than just looking for suggestions on how to go about doing it, please update the question to say so.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?  What problem are you having?  Or do you just want to be spoon-fed the code?